# Run entityframework cmdlets from my code

Tags: entity-framework-4.3, powershell-cmdlet

I am creating a small program over entityframework which allows to edit the POCOs with a UI.  as part of the process i would like to call the "add-migration" command from my code to save the interaction of the rest of the programmers with the program manager console.  is it possible at all?

thanks

Comment: So you are creating just UI for what powershell already gives you? What is wrong with using powershell?

Comment: we have a complex application with quite a few programmers.  I created a wrap for DB using EF code first.  the utility i created creates all the backing code for EF.  so since i gave the ability to edit pocos, i would also like to do the migrations automatically.  I dont want programmers to edit the pocos and then go to the powershell.  somewhere along the way someone will mess things up.

Comment: You mentioned you have programmers - aren't programmer supposed to write a code instead of using some GUI to "click" the code? Looks like you are putting great effort to make programmers live harder. Also there are already tools for POCO generation: EDMX + T4 templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add-Migration` cmdlet is defined in separate EF 4.3 Powershell assembly used by Package manager console. This assembly references a real EF 4.3 assembly. The core logic exposed from that assembly is `ToolingFacade` class from `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design` namespace. The exposed logic involves retrieving database and pending migrations and scaffolding a new migration but PowerShell assembly contains the execution workflow and creates bridge between EF, PowerShell and Visual studio (adding classes to your project) - this is what you must reverse engineer and reimplement in your tools.

Edit: You can also try to run `MigrationCommands.AddMigration` directly from PowerShell assembly.